# How do I order/reverse xml data or within a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, dataset, repeater

I've been trying to find out how I could simply reverse the data I get from an xml/order it by date or if I can do that withing the repeater, which renders them on the page.

So here is what I have:

Simply **the page reads an xml**...

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataSet messages = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                messages.ReadXml(MapPath("~/_xml/messages.xml"));
                myMessages.DataSource = messages;
                myMessages.DataBind();
            }
```

...and puts the date in a DataSet.

On the page, **a repeater renders the data**...

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myMessages" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table border="0">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="message">
                        <div class="messageHeader">
                            <span><p><b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %></b> wrote <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "date") %>:</p></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="splitLine"></div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="messageText">
                            <span><p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "message") %></p></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </Table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Maybe it's also possible to just write the data in a different order, like instead of putting new entries to the end of the file just put them at the beginning. But I think that's not really a solution.

So this is how I **write the data into an xml**:

```
var file = Server.MapPath("~/_xml/messages.xml");

var message = new XElement("contact",
new XElement("Name", s_name.Trim()),
new XElement("message", s_message.Trim()),
new XElement("date", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
var doc = new XDocument();

if (ckeckFileExistance(file))
{
     doc = XDocument.Load(file);
     doc.Element("messages").Add(message);
}
else
{
     doc = new XDocument(new XElement("messages", message));
}
doc.Save(file);
```

It's a quick and small project. It should be **as simple as possible**. And again. What I want to do is to **make the newest entries appear on the top of the page**. *Now they appear on the bottom*.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument messages = XDocument.Load(MapPath("~/_xml/messages.xml"));
myMessages.DataSource = 
    messages.Elements("messages")
    .Elements("contact")
    .OrderByDescending(m => DateTime.Parse(m.Element("date").Value))
myMessages.DataBind();
```

and change the repeater bindings to

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(((XElement)Container.DataItem).Element("date"), "Value")%>
```

etc

Comment: @webster69 See the edit above... Do you have the System.Xml.Linq namespace included?

Comment: Yes I do, but it still says that there is no definition of `messages.Elements`

Comment: @webster69 read the xml using XDocument.Load rather than ReadXml

Comment: Then how do I save the data in `messages` with `XDocument.Load()`?

Comment: You write the XML in the same way - you just read it differently

Comment: I know, but what do I do after I loaded the file with `XDocument.Load("~/_xml/messages.xml");`?

Comment: It says that it can't put the XDocument data inside a DataSet.
And this obviously doesn't work either: `XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("~/_xml/messages.xml");
                
                myMessages.DataSource = doc.Elements("messages").Elements("contact").OrderByDescending(m => DateTime.Parse(m.Element("date").Value));
                myMessages.DataBind();`

Comment: You need to mappath the file inside the load